# Using Qt widget from cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, qt

Is it possible to write (or reuse) some widget from Qt in native Cocoa application? For example, when I don’t need whole infrastructure, just one sort of “NSView” that I can – import to xcode cocoa project (like static library or so) – use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmacnativewidget.html

> The QMacNativeWidget class provides a widget for Mac OS X that provides a way to put Qt widgets into Carbon or Cocoa hierarchies depending on how Qt was configured.